# Eclipse GIT reindex loop plus append .gitignore

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, gitignore

After a clean install of STS - Spring Tool Suite, whenever it starts the indexing process never ends.

lots of `buiding workspace (Sleeping)` occour in the progress view

afted investigation, and just by luck I found opening Team View that .gitignore was appearing and desapearing.

Every time a new entry `/target`is appended to the file and it keep growing.

Does anyone know hot to stop this deadlock?

FIRST ATTEMPT

Just oppended Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Projects and disabled:

```
Automatic ignore derived resources by adding the to gitignore
```

looks the the loop finished. But no better explanation for this and if its the solution. Looks like not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just oppended Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Projects and disabled:

```
Automatic ignore derived resources by adding the to gitignore
```

looks the the loop finished. But no better explanation for this and if its the solution. Looks like not.